# 301 redirect blocked by cors although I allowed it in express and nginx

Tags: node.js, express, nginx, redirect, cors

I tried to make a login page with express js

Front : http://example.com
API : http://api.example.com

At http://example.com/login, there is login form.
I send id and password to API server with following code:

```
const url = 'http://api.example.com/login';
    fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(data),
    }).then((response) => {
        console.log(response.redirected);
        if (response.redirected) {
            response.redirect(response.url);
        }
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
    });
```

At http://api.example.com/login, I sent redirect response with following code:

```
// **** //
app.use(cors()); // I allowed cors aleardy, and checked it worked by fetching json data from other origin.
// **** //

app.post('/login', function(req, res) {
    const query = 'select id, password' + 
                  '  from user' +
                  " where id = '" + req.body.id + "'";

    db.query(query, (err, result) => {
        if (!!result) {
            if (result.length === 0) {
                res.send("no_id");
            } else {
                if (req.body.pw === result[0].password) {
                    res.redirect(301, 'http://example.com'); // if success to login, let browser go to main page from login page.
                }
                else {
                    console.log("wrong password");
                    res.send("worng_pw");
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            console.log(err);
        }
    });
});
```

and the main page, http://example.com/, is running on nginx.
so I allowed cors in nginx conf file. like this:

```
location / {
        
        ... (alias setting. it isn't reason of this cors error)

        if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
            add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain; charset=utf-8';
            add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
            return 204;
         }

        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' "$http_origin" always;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true' always;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS' always;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Accept,Authorization,Cache-Control,Content-Type,DNT,If-Modified-Since,Keep-Alive,Origin,User-Agent,X-Requested-With' always;

        try_files $uri $uri/ $uri/index.html $uri.html =404;
}
```

and then, when I tried to login I got this message from chorme.
`Access to fetch at 'http://example.com' (redirected from 'http://api.example.com/login') from origin 'http://www.example.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.`

Thanks to the nginx's cors setting for option method, I successed preflight request.
but main request always failed.

Fetching json always success, but 'only 301 redirect' failed by cors error.
I googled for a week, but I could't solve the problem.

How can I solve this problem?